# Appium - unable to locate elements in view

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

Android - real device.
appium-dotnet-driver v2.0.0.1
c# / vs2015

I have the following using uiautomatorviewer, link-image can be found here.

https://discuss.appium.io/t/cannot-locate-any-elements-in-this-view/12099

I am using the following command to locate the relative layout

ReadOnlyCollection linlayouts =
_driver.FindElementsByXPath(
"//android.widget.LinearLayout[@resource-id='com.mobilaurus.supershuttle:id/content_container']//android.widget.RelativeLayout");

as i cannot seem to locate any element in this view, all other views previous and later all work using id's and xpath's fine, for some reason this particular view appium cannot locate any items/elements - i was using driver.tap but the co-ordinates are different on several devices so not practical

I have extended the timeout but appium applies the find request and never comes back..

Anyone got any ideas as to why this would be or is there a way to always find the button at the bottom of the screen for devices.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an online xpath tester.

1) In the Appium Inspector hit the copy xml button
2) Use the xpath you provided above and see if you are receiving a unique element back

Sorry if this isn't helpful, something about your xpath just seems strange.

Comment: tried to get the source for this view via Appium Inspector but it was unable to, eventually an image was loaded but the layout was still showing the previous view then the inspector reported an timeout error

Comment: II am new to appium so I don't really have the experience to know what is going on here. The only thing I can think of is to select the refresh button and hopefully that resets the inspector (you likely have already done this). I would send a report to the appium discussion board with your appium log. Hopefully someone there can help you out.

Comment: By chance are you running on Nougat? Nougat is not currently supported in appium. https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6779

The behaviour you are seeing seems to match what I saw when I tried to test a Nougat device.

Comment: hi - no i am running marshmallow (6.0.1) - i have something listed on Appium boards already, just cannot work it out why this view and none of the others.

Comment: Wish I could be more helpful, do you mind linking the URL for the appium board? I would like to know the answer to this in case I run into this issue :)

Comment: hi - it's the link i put in original message https://discuss.appium.io/t/cannot-locate-any-elements-in-this-view/12099/7

Comment: further update :- this error seems to only happen on samsung S6, element search by id works fine on other devices